# PHP can't/won't compile without SQLite (this was working now it's not)?

Tags: php, compilation

I am trying to compile PHP 7.4.15:

```
    ./configure --enable-cli \
                --without-sqlite3 \
                --without-pdo-sqlite
```

Here is the error:

```
checking whether Intel CET is enabled... no
checking whether to enable the SQLite3 extension... yes
checking for sqlite3 > 3.7.4... no
configure: error: Package requirements (sqlite3 > 3.7.4) were not met:

No package 'sqlite3' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SQLITE_CFLAGS
and SQLITE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Why is it still giving me the error regarding SQLite?!?

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php#ref.pdo-sqlite.installation
>
> The PDO_SQLITE PDO driver is enabled by default. To disable,
> --without-pdo-sqlite[=DIR] may be used, where the optional [=DIR] is the sqlite base install directory. As of PHP 7.4.0 » libsqlite ≥ 3.5.0
> is required. Formerly, the bundled libsqlite could have been used
> instead, and was the default, if [=DIR] has been omitted.

Which makes no sense, the libsqlite latest version is only 3.34.1 not 3.5.0...

This was working earlier, I changed something and it all broke. Running just this command still breaks with the errors above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Uhm, I don't think there is a PHP version 7.5?

Comment: I just fixed that - typo - my bad

Comment: I think this `--without-pdo_sqlite` should be this `--without-pdo-sqlite`. Note the hyphen instead of an underscore

Comment: Note that version 3.34.1 is (a lot) higher than 3.5.0 if they don't use a really weird versioning system where each digit counts individually. Separate by the points.

Comment: Good catch on the underscore. Thats what I get for copy-paste programming. But the actual code was correct (believe it or not). Still same error - I updated code example above accordingly

Comment: @ArSen Thank you for input on the semantic versioning

Answer (score 0):

You need to install:-

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```